# Neo4j Java API, how to specify the path of creating database

Tags: java, database, eclipse, neo4j

According to the document of Neo4j, I tried below to create the database using Neo4j Java APIs in Eclipse:

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D:/Eclipse/Workplace/test");
```

and also tried to set the path under the Neo4j folder(`"D:\Neo4j3.0.1\workplace3"`). But I got the same error:

```
The method newEmbeddedDatabase(File) in the type GraphDatabaseFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Then I tried to import `java.io.File;` and add:

```
File dbpath = new File("D:/Neo4j3.0.1/workplace3");
org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(dbpath);
```

then the previous two packages are not used: `org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;`, `org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;` But I can compile the program and show "Done successfully" in the Eclipse console.

When I tried to connect to the database using neo4j-ce.exe, it gave me below Alert:

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@397b7f" was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
```

My code:

```
package com.peterlan522.neo4j.java.example;

import java.io.File;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;

public class Neo4jJavaAPIDBOperation {

public enum Tutorials implements Label { JAVA, SCALA, SQL, NEO4J,}
public enum TutorialRelationships implements RelationshipType { JVM_LANGIAGES, NON_JVM_LANGIAGES,}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    File dbpath = new File("D:/Neo4j3.0.1/workplace3");

    //GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D:/Eclipse/Workplace/test");

    org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(dbpath);

    try (org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {

        Node javaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.JAVA);
        javaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "JAVA001");
        javaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Java");
        javaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "25");
        javaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");                

        Node scalaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.SCALA);
        scalaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "SCALA001");
        scalaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Scala");
        scalaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "20");
        scalaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");

        Relationship relationship = javaNode.createRelationshipTo
        (scalaNode,TutorialRelationships.JVM_LANGIAGES);
        relationship.setProperty("Id","1234");
        relationship.setProperty("OOPS","YES");
        relationship.setProperty("FP","YES");
        tx.success();
        }
        System.out.print("Done successfully");
        }
}
```

Could anyone help on this? And give executable examples on this. Thank you so much!

Below are the softwares version:
Neo4j community version 3.0.1,
Eclipse Mars(4.5.0),
Java 1.8.0_91,
JRE System Library: JavaSE-1.8

And please get in below link to see the log.txt:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2xDq3--mwK4a0FoanlDengzVWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In your log there should be a stack trace at the point of failure.  You need to [edit] your post and copy/paste the stack trace into it so we can see what is actually causing the failure.

Comment: Try it with different workspace instead of "workplace3". It worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875024/error-in-executing-neo4j-cypher-query-by-java-embedded-mode